# Make one fixed div and another scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table

What I want is to make the top div to be fixed at the top and the second div should be scrollable. Both divs should behave the same column width.

I've tried to accomplish it through `position: fixed`, however, columns of divs are not exactly beneath one another.

It is not correct:

[image]

It is what I would like to have:

[image]

The code example looks like this:

```css
td,
th {
  width: 4%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 7rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
}

.scrollable {
  margin-top: 7rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="fixed">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look to the sticky property, maybe it can help

Comment: Remove padding from .fixed div can be a solution

Comment: @Sfili_81 no, I tried, but columns are not beneath one another.

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kt5zqned/)?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I am sorry, but I am from mobile phone and this link cannot be opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work nicely for you. Essentially, I just went through and cleaned everything up and gave the `mainContainer` some scroll functionality. Just ensure whatever content you want to come after the scroll `div` is still nested within the `mainContainer` div.

```css
td,
th {
  width: 4%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  max-height: 170px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 7rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="fixed">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company 1</td>
        <td>Contact 1</td>
        <td>Country 1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p style="color: #fff; text-align: center;"> some other content here that is still nested in the main-container div </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.fixed {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: orange;
}

.scrollable {
   
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vz6tjwsp/

EDIT: Changed **top** from 1px to 0px.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Upvoted. But I've used a little bit more complicated example than this and it sometimes does not work. Maybe you have a solution with `position: fixed`?

Comment: Does your top div height change?

Comment: yeah, top div height changes

Comment: I do not have a solution. With fixed positioning you would need manually set the width in  order to line up your columns but then as soon as your window size changes your columns would be misaligned.